# HTML5 pattern need help making a specific pattern for an input

Tags: html, regex

Im trying to make a pattern that will allow input such as `SB 0023467-01` or `ST 0023467-02`

```
<input type="text" name="surat_beranak" pattern="[S]+[B\s]+[0-9]{7}+[-]+[0]+[^0-1]"  
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Format SB 0029384-01')"value="<?= $surat_beranak;?>" 
    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Surat Beranak Number" required>
```

This is my current input pattern, but it's not working as intended. I need help where the pattern will allow only `S` as the first letter, then `B` or `T` as the second letter, then have a space after. Then there will be **7** numeric digits followed by a dash and a number, `0` then `1` or `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `+` between every character, which allows a character to be repeated many times. It is the equivalent of using `{1,}`. `[0-9]{7}+` is invalid.

You're using square brackets, allowing different characters to be used in a same place. A good place to use these would be for the beginning: `S[BT]` would allow SB or ST. There is no need to wrap single characters with these brackets.

Your current pattern ends with `[^0-1]`, which means "every character except 0 and 1". It goes against your goal of having "01" or "02" at the end.

**Your pattern, in HTML, would be `S[BT] [0-9]{7}-0[12]`.** If you're using this pattern anywhere else, you should wrap it between `^` and `$`, in order to only allow the input you want, and nothing else.

In the future, please use regex testers in order to test your pattern. [Example with the working pattern and a few input examples](https://regex101.com/r/OUrZfX/2).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, i'll do a better job of asking a question next time and making sure to have the right tags.